# JSONDecodeError and FileNotFoundError When Loading word2vec-google-news-300 Model with Gensim in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, gensim

I am trying to load the `word2vec-google-news-300` model using Gensim in Python, but I am encountering a FileNotFoundError followed by a JSONDecodeError. The errors occur when Gensim attempts to use its downloader to fetch the model. Here's the relevant part of my code:

```
import gensim.downloader as api

model = api.load("word2vec-google-news-300")
```

**The first error message:**
`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/myusername/gensim-data/information.json'`

**The second error message:**
`json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

**Troubleshooting steps**

1. Confirmed the '/Users/myusername/gensim-data' directory does indeed exist and made sure it has the right read/write/exec permissions (rwxrwx-r)
2. Created an empty 'information.json' file inside the gensim-data folder (incase Gensim would recognize it)
3. Cleared gensim cache by deleting the gensim-data directory, and then running the script again so that Gensim would recreate the directory
4. Reinstalled Gensim with pip uninstall gensim and then pip install gensim

Despite all this the problem persists :(... I'm running Python 3.11 in VSCode and Gensim 4.3.2 on a Mac M1.

Trying to finish an assignment for my AI course, but this issue's taken up so much time, so I really appreciate any help or insight on how I can fix this, thank you!!

**EDIT**

I alternatively downloaded the model manually from [GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7XkCwpI5KDYNlNUTTlSS21pQmM/edit?resourcekey=0-wjGZdNAUop6WykTtMip30g)

and changed the model usage to instead use the downloaded version, using KeyedVectors instead of gensim.downloader as api:

```
from gensim.models import KeyedVectors

model_path = '/Users/myusername/Downloads/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz'  
model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(model_path, binary=True)
```

This seems to have worked, but the assignment requires me to 'First, use gensim.downloader.load to load the word2vec-google-news-300 pretrained embedding model', so even though this workaround works I still need to figure out how to instead use the load method

Comment: Did you try update gensim with ''' pip install --upgrade gensim ''' ?

Comment: Did you try specifying a different cache directory when loading the model?
'''
model = api.load("word2vec-google-news-300", cache_dir='/path/to/your/cache')
'''

Comment: I did try upgrating gensim with pip install --upgrade gensim indeed.
I tried specifying a different cache directory but that seems to raise another error (TypeError: load() got an unexpected keyword argument 'cache_dir')
No change :(

Comment: what about adding this before the load: ''' api.download("word2vec-google-news-300", cache='/path/to/your/cache') ''' ? Then, the load you pass it normally without the cache parameter

Comment: Did you try manually downloading it? I will try to reproduce this here in my env

Comment: Tried the cache before load, doesn't seem to work.

I alternatively downloaded the model manually, and that method seems to work, but the assignment requires me to use the loader method so I guess I can't use this workaround instead :(((( (see edit for more info)